# Image Hyperlink to WWW using local cell referencing

Tags: microsoft-excel, images, hyperlink, cells

**The scenario:**

Manual input data in local excel file.  I then click an adjacent image to run a preset hyperlink, to a specific web page, with part data captured from a specific cell. this is 100% possible if you click a standard hyperlink command in a cell but would like it to run from an image click.

**The issue:**

I want to pick up the manual data input, from the cell and include this in the hyperlink reference, attached to the image.

**An example or specifically:**

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://ashberg.de/php-barcode/code=",$B$4,"&scale=2&bar=ANY"))
```

This runs perfectly from a cell click.

**History:**

I have used Concat to join the three sections together. The result is giving me ",$B$4" at the web page Of-which works perfectly if you click the containing formula cell, but I would like this to happen if I click an image.

`$B$4` refers to the manual input cell specifically. An example of input string is `B000CDINNG`

Comment: I suggest you add screenshots to make your question, and what you are trying to accomplish, easier to understand.

Comment: I believe this to be written as simply and clearly as possible, in terms of understanding. What is required is a hyperlink action attached to an image that picks up contents/variable data from a specific cell reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use VBA although it's not clear what exactly your use case is, and whether you can afford to enable macros.

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1"), _
Address:="https://ashberg.de/php-barcode/?code=" & Range("B4").Value & "&scale=2&bar=ANY"
```

You don't specify how often, if ever, the relevant cell contents change: the macro would have to be run each time, possibly attached to an Open or Change event.

Comment: Great thank you. To avoid VBA code. Would it work if i hyperlinked to a cell icking up the cell in a concat, then setting an action that 'on access to cell' it jumps to the webpage?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you mean, I don't believe that's possible.